# How can we conda install packages have been downloaded successfully, ignoring download failed packages?

Tags: python, conda, anaconda3

everyone:

Because of the speed of network,  when I conda install some packages, there will exist some related packages can not be downloaded completely. But we can not install packages have been downloaded successfully without other "related" packages(maybe "related" means the best march in version, but not necessary).
For example, When I install pytorch, it need numpy-1.14.2, but I am with numpy-1.15.1. I don't need verson 1.14.2 numpy in practice.

So I am a little confused how to make "conda" trying to install packages have been downloaded successfully, ignoring download failed packages?

Thanks!

EricKani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the conda documentation there are two options that may help https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/install.html

> --no-update-deps
> Do not update or change already-installed dependencies.
>
> --no-deps
> Do not install, update, remove, or change dependencies. This WILL lead to broken environments and inconsistent behavior. Use at your own
> risk.

I believe by default conda tries with --no-update-deps first and then if that fails tries to update deps; giving it that option will make sure some version of each needed package is installed, if not necessarily the latest.

You could try --no-deps as well, which will literally prevent conda from installinh ANYTHING other than the exact packages you tell it to, but things may not work with that.